# Dim background when opening JDialog in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, opacity, jdialog

Is that possible. I tried setting opacity of the Jframe and set background but it didn't work out. Is there some easy and elegant way?

Comment: Can you add your codes to this question, it will be helpful for us to help you.

Comment: Oh yeah I will do that tomorrow :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by setting the JFrame’s glassPane to a visible JPanel with a translucent background:

```
static void setDimmed(JFrame frame,
                      boolean dimmed) {

    JComponent newGlassPane = new JPanel();
    if (dimmed) {
        newGlassPane.setBackground(new Color(0x80000000, true));
    }
    frame.setGlassPane(newGlassPane);
    newGlassPane.setVisible(dimmed);
}
```